Gradle sub-project to pick up the postgres configuration for Flyway migration in Spring Boot application
I have the clean architecture project setup
Identity
| — Core
|   — build.gradle.kts
| — Web
|   — src
|       — main
|           — resources
|               — application.properties
|   — build.gradle.kts
| — External
|    - src
|       - main
|         - resources
|           - db
|             - migration
|               - .sql files
|   — build.gradle.kts
| — settings.gradle.kts

settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "Identity"
include("Web")
include("Core")
include("External")

In the web project, I have the database connection string in application.properties as below
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school_staff
spring.datasource.username=keycloak
spring.datasource.password=******

Now in the external project, I have the flyway libraries below
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "11.0.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.4.0")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.4")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:11.0.1")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:11.0.1")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:11.0.1")
}

I am using flyway gradle plugin and then When I run the migration command from the Identity location
./gradlew flywayMigrate

Exception
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :External:flywayMigrate FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':External:flywayMigrate'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
  Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!

The command not able to find the db connection. I don't want to duplicate the connection string, I want the gradle command to pick up the connection string from the application.properties file

Can you try to move the flywaydb plugin to the Web module where data source is configured and run ./gradlew -p Web flywayMigrate. BR

@RoarS. I am generating all the migrations in the external project as per the clean architecture. If the move the plugin to the web project. The external project has no reference of the web project. In this case I'll not be able to generate all the migration files on the external project.
